# Why does GCC emit "lea" instead of "sub" for subtraction?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, compiler-optimization, gnu-assembler

I am looking at some assembly that was generated by disassembling some C programs and I am confused by a single optimization that I see repeated frequently.

When I have no optimizations on the GCC compiler uses the `subl` instruction for subtraction, but when I do have optimizations turned on (`-O3` to be precise) the compiler uses a `leal` instruction instead of subtraction, example below:

without optimizations:

```
83 e8 01     subl $0x1, %eax
```

with optimizations

```
8d 6f ff     leal -0x1(%edi), %ebp
```

Both of these instructions are 3 bytes long, so I am not seeing an optimization here. Could someone help me out and try to explain the compiler's choice ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the original C code that produces this.

But if I had to guess, it's because the `leal` allows the subtraction to be done out-of-place without destroying the source register.

This can save an extra register move.

---

The first example:

```
83 e8 01     subl $0x1, %eax
```

overwrites `%eax` thereby destroying the original value.

The second example :

```
8d 6f ff     leal -0x1(%edi), %ebp
```

stores `%edi - 1` into `%ebp`. `%edi` is preserved for future use.

Comment: I hadn't considered it from this perspective because the non-optimized version only uses immediate values in the subtractions. Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 11):

Keep in mind also that `lea` does not affect the flags whereas `sub` does. So if the ensuing instructions do not depend on the flags being updated by the subtraction then *not* updating the flags will be more efficient as well.

Comment: If `lea` does not affect flags, then how is it equivalent to `sub`? Should it not affect the flags to have the same effect as `sub`?

Comment: @crisron they are not equivalent and serve different purposes. If you don't want/need side effects, use lea, otherwise use sub

Comment: Citation needed re efficiency?  I don't think updating flags requires extra uops.  And I'd assume flags are subject to register renaming, so subsequent instructions that don't look at the flags won't be delayed to wait for the flags update.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Indeed, this sounds like nonsense.  x86 CPUs need to rename FLAGS to run normal x86 code efficiently, because most integer instructions *do* update FLAGS.  Moreover, integer register-file entries have room for FLAGS, so an instruction that writes an output register and FLAGS still takes 1 physical register-file entry.  Pentium 4 had a false output-dependency effect with instructions like `inc` that only wrote *some* FLAGS, but `sub` writes them all.  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095)

Comment: [Does it cost significant resources for a modern CPU to keep flags updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64817587)